# scipy.optimize.leastsq error not an array of floats

Tags: python, numpy, error-handling, scipy, mathematical-optimization

This is my code

```
import os
import sys
import numpy as np
import scipy
from scipy.optimize import leastsq


def peval (inp_mat,p):
    m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7 = p
    out_mat = np.array(np.zeros(inp_mat.shape,dtype=np.float32))
    mid = inp_mat.shape[0]/2
    for xy in range(0,inp_mat.shape[0]):
        if (xy<(inp_mat.shape[0]/2)):
            out_mat[xy] = ( (  (inp_mat[xy+mid]*m0)+(inp_mat[xy]*m1)+ m2 ) /( (inp_mat[xy+mid]*m6)+(inp_mat[xy]*m7)+1 ) )
        else:
            out_mat[xy] = ( (  (inp_mat[xy]*m3)+(inp_mat[xy-mid]*m4)+ m5 ) /( (inp_mat[xy]*m6)+(inp_mat[xy-mid]*m7)+1 ) )
    return np.array(out_mat)

def residuals(p, out_mat, inp_mat):
    m0,m1,m2,m3,m4,m5,m6,m7 = p
    err=np.array(np.zeros(inp_mat.shape,dtype=np.float32))
    if (out_mat.shape == inp_mat.shape):
        for xy in range(0,inp_mat.shape[0]):
            err[xy] =  err[xy]+ (out_mat[xy] -inp_mat[xy])
        return np.array(err)




f = open('/media/anilil/Data/Datasets/repo/txt_op/vid.txt','r')
x = np.loadtxt(f,dtype=np.int16,comments='#',delimiter='\t')
nof = x.shape[0]/72 # Find the number of frames
x1 = x.reshape(-1,60,40)
x1_1= x1[0,:,:].flatten()
x1_2= x1[1,:,:].flatten()

x= []
y= []

for xy in range(1,50,1):
    y.append(x1[xy,:,:].flatten())
    x.append(x1[xy-1,:,:].flatten())

x=np.array(x,dtype=np.float32)
y=np.array(y,dtype=np.float32)
length =  x1_1.shape#initail guess
p0 = np.array([1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],dtype=np.float32)

abc=leastsq(residuals, p0,args=(y,x))
print ('Size of first matrix is '+str(x1_1.shape))
print ('Size of first matrix is '+str(x1_2.shape))

print ("Done with program")
```

I have tried adding np.array in most places with no use.
Could someone please help me ?

Another question here is do I give the output of the residuals() as a single value by adding all `errorsnp.sum(err,axis=1)`. or leave it the way it is ?

When I `return np.sum(err,axis=1)` in the function `residuals()`. There is no change in the initial guess. It just remains the same.

I.E error is for each item in the input output mapping. or a combined error overall ?

[Example data.](http://pastebin.com/VutTTTSM)

## Output

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/anilil/Data/charm/mv_clean/.idea/nose_reduction_mpeg.py", line 49, in <module>
    abc=leastsq(residuals, p0,args=(y,x))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py", line 378, in leastsq
    gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
minpack.error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

Comment: Could you share the data you are using or at least a subset of it?

Comment: Added the data you wanted

Comment: Slightly too late, Simon was faster: You indeed only have to replace `np.array(err)` by e.g. `np.ravel(err)` or `err.flatten()` and it runs through. Check also the questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23769508/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-not-a-proper-array-of-floats-error) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18579476/scipy-optimize-curve-fit-error-result-from-function-not-a-proper-array-of-float)

Answer (score 1):

`leastsq` requires a 1D array to be returned from your `residuals` function.

Currently you calculate the residuals for the whole image and return that as a 2D array.

The simple fix would be to flatten the array of residuals (turning your 2D array into a 1D one).

So instead of returning

```
return np.array(err)
```

Do this instead

```
return err.flatten()
```

Note that `err` is already a numpy array so doesn't need to be cast before the return (I guess that slipped in when you were trying to debug it!)

Comment: Tried it..It doesn't throw any error but the p0 never changes.. make me think I did something wrong.

Comment: `leastsq` doesn't modify p0 in place. Instead it returns the optimal parameters. (As well as some other stuff) see this http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.leastsq.html for details. You would want the x in the list of things that it returns.